# Zero Width Character space adding funny characters to Power BI Field

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Code Sample 1

```
Table.AddColumn(
    ToList, 
    "AddInvisibleChars", 
    each 
    List.Transform(
        [Chars], 
        each 
        if 
        List.Contains(LowerCaseChars, _) 
        then 
        _ & Character.FromNumber(8023) 
        else _
        )
        ),
```

I use this to fool the Power BI to be case sensitive. When I look under the bonnet it has added these special characters to the field. I export the table using Dax studio into a csv file to see these .

```
Po Number - Crâ€‹eâ€‹dâ€‹iâ€‹tâ€‹ Caâ€‹râ€‹dâ€‹

"Zero Width Space in UTF CODES
UTF-8 (hex)
0xE2 0x80 0x8B (e2808b)"

â€‹  - These are the extra hidden characters added in this Power BI field under the covers .

€
20AC
0128 

â
00E2
0226

‹
2039
0139"
```

What is going on and how do I stop this without switching off the case sensitivity fix for the power Bi front end?

Character.FromNumber(8023)

> Character.FromNumber function is an equivalent of Chr function in VBA or ‘String’.charCodeAt() for Javascript. It returns the Ascii code character from the number. The example shown above will return the non-alphanumerical characters. So by using this, you can replace all the non-alphanumerical characters from the text string.

Trying UTF 8 encoding on this field at the end results in the funny characters changing to a ?.

```
Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Replaced Value1",
    {
     "number" ,
     each if (_ = null or _ = "") then null
          else Text.FromBinary(Text.ToBinary(_,1251), TextEncoding.UTF8)
    }
  )
```

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: You are trying to convert lower case letters to ____ ?

Comment: Add a zero width character space to each lower case letter as per Chris Webb's solution for case sensitivity issue in Power BI https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Case-Sensitivity-in-the-Power-Front-end-and-Character-Encoding/td-p/2127500

Comment: Those "extra" characters is actually the ZWS character.  The representation of ZWS, Hex encoded for UTF8, is `E2 80 8B`. The program you are using to examine the CSV is apparently returning them as separate characters, however.  If I open the file in Notepad++, it appears normal.  I suppose you could get rid of them in the CSV file with an appropriate editor.

Comment: Interesting . The Power BI Front end needs them, But then the data field goes into a power App and end up in SharePoint list . If there was a way of removing these characters that do not display to the naked eye . It only when you export to csv you see them or when u import them in somewhere that there are seen in the character length of the field as 3 extra characters. So if you look at the SharePoint list u cannot see them , only when you export it to csv.

Comment: If I export the data from Power BI directly to a CSV and then open the CSV in notepad++ or notepad, they are not visible.

Comment: I have used Dax studio and exported these to csv  and the extra characters are present and visible that way. The extra characters are the ZWS I have added in the Character.FromNumber(8023) . Problem is that I need them in the Power BI End for them to force case sensitivity in the Power BI Front end . I dont then need them when I send the data from the Power App to the SharePoint .  From the SharePoint they then directly go to Azure Data Bricks via data factory .  I think I should look at the Power App and see if there is a way of removing the zero length character space characters  there ?

Comment: That makes sense, unless they don't matter to the final target.

Answer (score 0):

The code for Zero-Width-Character should be 8203 instead of 8023.